# Azure Active Directory - get tenant list

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am aware of the Powershell cmdlet [Get-AzTenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-aztenant?view=azps-3.0.0) and the [REST API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) `GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2019-06-01` to query the AD tenants wrt the current user context.

As this requires user_impersonation wrt Azure Resource Management, is there an alternative with i.e. Microsoft Graph?

An example, where this list of tenants is used

- Microsoft Access Panel 
  https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/profile/organizations

  POST  https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/responsive/multidirectoryinfo
- Azure DevOps profile
  https://aex.dev.azure.com/me
- Azure Portal
  POST https://portal.azure.com/api/directories/List

Comment: Without a user authenticated, how would you expect the API to know which tenents to return?

Comment: I want to issue the call within the user context. I want to use the an API that needs less permissions than user_impersonation wrt https://management.azure.com.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such API in Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph.

> I want to use the an API that needs less permissions than user_impersonation wrt management.azure.com.

Besides, I think the delegated permission `user_impersonation` is not large, when the user login the app and consent the permission, the app just calls the API as the user. The permissions are all from and decided by the user, not the app.

Comment: Please correct me as my understanding is, if a user consents to user_impersonation, then the app can do everything the user can do... there is no 'higher' permission that can be granted to an app by a non-Azure AD admin.

Comment: @FlorianEckert Hi, any other concern? If it is helpful, please accept it as answer, thanks.